# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ',' in @rnmapbox/maps module's Mapbox.ts

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, mapbox

I am facing an issue with the @rnmapbox/maps module in my React Native project. When I try to bundle the index.js file, I encounter the following error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\WORK\plotlot\plotlot-25398\android\node_modules\@rnmapbox\maps\src\Mapbox.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (5:7)

  3 |   Camera,
  4 |   UserTrackingMode,
> 5 |   type CameraPadding,
    |        ^
  6 |   type CameraAnimationMode,
  7 |   type CameraBounds,
  8 | } from './components/Camera';
```

The error seems to be pointing to the Mapbox.ts file in the @rnmapbox/maps module. Specifically, it's related to the import statement from the Camera module. Line 5 is where the issue is occurring, and the parser expects a comma after type CameraPadding, but something unexpected seems to be causing the problem.

This is the code I am trying to run

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View ,Text} from 'react-native';
import Mapbox from '@rnmapbox/maps';

Mapbox.setAccessToken('access_token');

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>test</Text>
                <Mapbox.MapView style={styles.map} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    container: {
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

dependecies

"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.5",
"@rnmapbox/maps": "10.0.4",